# PhoneGap - Javascript does not show any response

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm trying to use the [Cache Plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/876) so I just tried to execute the code from the documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady);
function onDeviceReady()
{
    var success = function(status) {
        alert('Message: ' + status);
    }

    var error = function(status) {
        alert('Error: ' + status);
    }

    window.cache.clear( success, error );
}
```

And I'm trying to call it with a button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="onDeviceReady()"> Click me </button>
```

But when I click the button nothing happens.
Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Any error in `logcat` ?

Answer (score 0):

You got to include "cordova.js" file in your html. This file gets created in project root folder during cordova build and its essential in order to make use of cordova plugins.

Comment: I did! i linked cordova.js and cordova_plugin.js in the head element to my code

Comment: @JietzoRawit i guess ondeviceready event listener should either be placed inside body onload function or jquery document ready function if use jquery. Thats how it works for me